# Label function based x coordinate of a given function

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2,samples=100]
    \draw[font=\small,-Stealth] (-3,0)  -- (3,0) node[right]{$x$} ;
    \draw[font=\small,-Stealth] (0,-2)  -- (0,2) node[above]{$y$};
        \foreach \x in {-1,0,...,1}
            \draw (\x, -2pt) -- ++ (0,4pt);%[shift={(2,1.5)}]
        \foreach \y in {-1,0,...,1}
            \draw (-2pt, \y) -- ++ (4pt, 0);%[shift={(2,1.5)}]
    \clip[rounded corners=10pt] (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
    \node[label=left:{$f(x) =x^2$}] at (-1.5,1.25) {};
    \draw[color=red,thick] plot (\x,{(\x)^2-1});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to have a node definition that labels the function at a specified x coordinate?

Say I want the label of the function to be at the x coordinate `x=-1.5`, then it would automatically calculate the correct coordinates for such label; in this case `y=(-1.5)^2-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the purpose of `declare function`. That is, you can declare a function via

```
declare function={f(\x)=(\x)^2-1;}
```

and then use it e.g. in

```
\node[label={[font=\footnotesize]left:{$f(x) =x^2$}}] at (-1.5,{f(-1.5)}) {};
```

which now knows the value of the function at `x=-1.5`, or in

```
\draw[color=red,thick] plot (\x,{f(\x)});
```

which plots the function. (It is better to use an odd number of samples for symmetric plots, and 100 samples is rather generous, you may want to reduce the sample number and use the `smooth` key.)

Full code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2,samples=101,declare function={f(\x)=(\x)^2-1;}]
    \draw[font=\small,-Stealth] (-3,0)  -- (3,0) node[right]{$x$} ;
    \draw[font=\small,-Stealth] (0,-2)  -- (0,2) node[above]{$y$};
        \foreach \x in {-1,0,...,1}
            \draw (\x, -2pt) -- ++ (0,4pt);%[shift={(2,1.5)}]
        \foreach \y in {-1,0,...,1}
            \draw (-2pt, \y) -- ++ (4pt, 0);%[shift={(2,1.5)}]
    \node[label={[font=\footnotesize]left:{$f(x) =x^2$}}] at (-1.5,{f(-1.5)}) {};
    \clip[rounded corners=10pt] (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
    \draw[color=red,thick] plot (\x,{f(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that in `pgfplots` 1-dimensional plots (of this type) are paths, so you can add labels by specifying the position along the path.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=(\x)^2-1;}]
 \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,ymax=2.2,ymin=-1.2,
    xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$}]
  \addplot[color=red,domain=-2:2,smooth,semithick] {f(x)}
    node[pos=0.275,below left] {$f(x)$};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One could add that in `pgfplots` the plots are paths, and you can add labels via `node[pos=0.3,below left]{...}`, say.

Comment: Can you edit your post to reflect your comment? Thanks.

Comment: @azetina Sure. Done.